# can't set UITableViewCell as a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have made a `ViewController`, in that `ViewController`, I have made a `TableView` , in the `TableView` I have added a `TableViewCell`.
In the `TableViewCell`, I have added a text label and an image.
Iv'e made a cocoa touch file named `customCell` and connected it with the TableView Cell.

In the `ViewController` file I wrote this:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell:customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCell
            cell.imageCountry.image = UIImage(named: "2xd.png")
            cell.nameCountry.text = "hey"
return cell
```

This is what i wrote in the customCell file:
import UIKit

```
class customCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var imageCountry: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var nameCountry: UILabel!

}
```

Iv'e connected the TableView & the ViewController with the DataSource & Delegate.
When I run my code this is the error I get:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x10d1119f0) to 'refreshing.customCell' (0x10b2f6dd0).
```

*refreshing is the name of the project.

And the green line of the bugger is set to this line:

```
let cell:customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCell
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hope this would help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812168/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uitableviewcell-to-appname-customcellname

Comment: @Rambo Tried both answers in the link, I get another error in the AppDelegate.swift file in this line: 
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate

Comment: It sounds like the cell associated with the "cell" identifier isn't defined as a `customCell`.  When you say "connected it with the TableView Cell", how did you actually do that?

Comment: @PhillipMills In the MainStoryboard>ViewController>Table View>Cell>Identifier:"cell"

Comment: Did you also set the cell's class to be `customCell` in the storyboard?

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes Phillip. Did I miss here something I have done wrong?

Comment: Make sure you've set the cell's class in the Identity Inspector tab in the Utilities menu (right menu) and that your custom class subclasses UITableViewCell

Comment: @jrisberg can you show an example code please?

Comment: @Eliko see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the old decking method, that either rquires you to create the cell or use the new that takes the indexPath

```
let cell:customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! customCell
```

if it is still failing, you need to register the cell, either by setting it up in the storyboard or by registering either a class or a nib file in code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "customCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
```

or

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.registerClass(customCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
```

Comment: before you edited, I added this line:
`tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "customCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCellOne")`
And it worked! I wanted to ask why, because when i type `cell` it has error (like you edited)

Comment: the error is: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:` and then a lot of lines of errors.. why does it work when i put an identifier which is not named "**cell**"?

Comment: sure u didn't once use registerNib and once registerClass?

Comment: Before using Nib I used Class but when I used Nib I did `//` to the Class. Why is it matter?

Answer (score 0):

[image: You need to set your custom class as the cell's class here]

You need to set your custom class as the cell's class here ^

And to subclass, ensure in your CustomClass.h file you have

`@interface CustomClass : UITableViewCell`

Comment: where do I type this line?:
@interface CustomClass : UITableViewCell

Comment: It should be one of the first lines in your CustomCell.h file, after any imports

Comment: But it looks like you did that actually, I missed that in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! the answer of @vikingosegundo helped me, see my comment in his answer why