# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to 'AppName.CustomCellName'

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift2

I am trying to create a custom cell that expands on tap. I am using this github example: https://github.com/rcdilorenzo/Cell-Expander

This line gives runtime error SIGABRT:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    (cell as! EventTableViewCell).watchFrameChanges()
    //Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x105aa1b80) to 'AppName.EventTableViewCell' (0x104287fe0).
}
```

I also checked answer from this post, followed three steps, but no luck:
[Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to '(AppName).(CustomCellName)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812168/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uitableviewcell-to-appname-customcellname)

My custom cell class looks like  this:

```
import UIKit

class EventTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
...
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( "eventCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let date = self.eventArray[indexPath.row].startTime
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let minutes = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: date)
    var minutesString: String
    if (minutes == 0) {
        minutesString = "00"
    } else {
        minutesString = String(calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: date))
    }
    let hours = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: date)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.eventArray[indexPath.row].title + " - \(hours):\(minutesString)"

    return cell
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: show your code for method cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @MobileMon edited the question^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to '(AppName).(CustomCellName)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812168/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uitableviewcell-to-appname-customcellname)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"I have self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventCell") in my viewDidLoad"

That's probably overriding the value you set in the storyboard. Try removing this line, or change it to `self.tableView.registerClass(EventTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventCell")`.

Comment: I was making my Table View programmatically and not setting the custom cell name in the `registerClass` method was what caused the error for me.

Answer (score 2):

In the storyboard, click on the cell and set the class name to EventTableViewCell instead of UITableViewCell

Or if you are doing everything programmatically, in cellForRowAtIndexPath do this instead:

```
 var cell : EventTableViewCell?
 cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! EventTableViewCell?
 if cell == nil {
           cell = EventTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "eventCell")
 }
return cell
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the cell you're getting is an instance of `EventTableViewCell`? Did you register your custom cell class with `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`?

If you change your code from this:

```
(cell as! EventTableViewCell).watchFrameChanges()
```

to this:

```
(cell as? EventTableViewCell)?.watchFrameChanges()
```

do you still get the exception?

Also, are you using the same storyboard from the GitHub example? If so, did you update the storyboard to use your cell class name and reuse identifier? You are using EventTableViewCell/"eventCell" but the original code used PickerTableViewCell/"cell".

Comment: I have 
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventCell")  

in my viewDidLoad, and eventCell is the identifier from the storyboard. It indeed has to do something with registering cell, because your code works, but when I try to drag cell (other function), I get same error:
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x10d29eb80) to 'CallIn.EventTableViewCell

Comment: I am not using same storyboard, I use mine, which I adapted to fit.

Comment: If you have defined "eventCell" in the storyboard, I don't think you need to explicitly register it in code. 

What type did you set for the cell in the storyboard? Is it EventTableViewCell?

Comment: if you are not using storyboard are you using a xib?

Comment: @MobileMon - I think he means that he's not using the same storyboard from the GitHub project, he is using his own storyboard.

Comment: yes, I use my storyboard, and I changed it. 
Yes, I have class of the cell in storyboard: EventTableViewCell and identifier: eventCell..

Comment: when I hit the cell, my method didSelectRowAtIndexPath does not fire. Why?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, what type is your cell instance?

Comment: "I have self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventCell")" - try removing this line, or change it to `self.tableView.registerClass(EventTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventCell")`.

Comment: this worked for now :) thank you, can you put this as an answer, I will accept it?

Comment: Glad to help. Answer added.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

As @Greg Brown said, solution was to change the type of the cell to custom cell class:

```
//wrong:
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventCell") 

//right:
self.tableView.registerClass(EventTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "eventCell")
```