# Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x11e159aa0) to 'test.CourseItemTableViewCell'

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view with a table view cell. I'm trying to implement a table view with multiple cell types. When I do, I get the following error

Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x11e159aa0) to 'test.CourseItemTableViewCell'

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CourseItemTableViewCell

            cell.refreshUI()
            
            cell.cellIndex = indexPath
            cell.dataSource = self
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            return cell;
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! BookItemTableViewCell

            cell.refreshUI()
            
            cell.cellIndex = indexPath
            cell.dataSource = self
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            return cell;
            
        }
```

How can I implement multiple cell types in the table view? I want one row to have one cell type and the other to be of another cell type.

Comment: the tableview cell with identifier cell can/should only be of one type, you should use bookCell and courseCell identifiers to distinguish them

Comment: do you have examples of both cell types defined in your storyboard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' to '(AppName).(CustomCellName)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812168/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uitableviewcell-to-appname-customcellname)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's that you haven't registered both cells. Here's something I have to show you what I'm talking about:

I have a `UITableView` that dynamically displays any of three types of cells... `NSNumber`, `CIColor`, and (not shown in this code) `NSVector`. Depending on the custom cells, you have pairs of labels and sliders - 1, 3, and 2 respectively.

Restricting this to `NSNumber` (one slider) and `CIColor` (three sliders), with properly working subclassed `UITableCells`, all I needed to do to render these two are:

1. Properly register **both** cell types in `viewDidLoad`. Please note, this is what I think you are missing:

   ```
   tblAttributes.register(NSNumberCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: NSNumberCell.identifier)
   tblAttributes.register(CIColorCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CIColorCell.identifier)
   ```
2. Detect through code which cell type you want to render in `tableView(cellForRowAt:)`. Note, my code should **never** return a `UITableViewCell`:

   ```
   switch attributes[indexPath.row].attributeClass {
   case "NSNumber":
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NSNumberCell.identifier) as! NSNumberCell
       // [populate label and slider defaults here]
       return cell
   case "CIColor":
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CIColorCell.identifier) as! CIColorCell
       // [populate label and slider defaults here]
       return cell
   default:
       // this should never happen
       return UITableViewCell()
   }
   ```

All told, it seems that `CourseItemTableViewCell` and `BookItemTableViewCell` are not uniquely identified.

And here's how I subclassed my cells:

```
class NSNumberCell:UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = String(describing: NSNumberCell.self)

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // [custom code here]
    }
}
```

Same thing for the other custom cells.